# Error: curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Tags: csv, curl, terminal

I get the error: curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

When running:

```
curl 'http://www.ncedc.org/cgi-bin/catalog-search2.pl' \

-H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://ncedc.org' \

-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \

-data 'format=nccsv&mintime=1967%2F01%2F01%2C00%3A00%3A00&maxtime=&minmag=2.5&maxmag=&mindepth=&maxdepth=&minlat=&maxlat=&minlon=&maxlon=&etype=E&keywds=&outputloc=web&searchlimit=1000000' - compressed \

| sed '/^</d' > earthquakes-smaller.csv
```

I get the data to display in the terminal with:

```
curl 'http://www.ncedc.org/cgi-bin/catalog-search2.pl' \

-H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://ncedc.org' \

-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \

--data 'format=nccsv&mintime=1978%2F01%2F01%2C00%3A00%3A00&maxtime=&minmag=0.5&maxmag=&mindepth=&maxdepth=&minlat=&maxlat=&minlon=&maxlon=&etype=E&keywds=&outputloc=web&searchlimit=1000000' --compressed
```

but, I'd like to put it in a CSV so I can play with it.  I tried a few tweaks to the first query with no success.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like in the first invocation, you use `- compressed` instead of `--compressed`, does that make a difference?

Comment: Thanks I missed that part!  When I used --compressed and --data it worked.  The tutorial I'm following is here: https://medium.com/vis-gl/animating-40-years-of-california-earthquakes-e4ffcdd4a289 if you would like to reference it

Comment: I've left a comment on the gist that contains the typo, thanks!